# Java: can't insert data from servlet's doPost using jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have a

**`BaseRunner`** class: connects to a database and has methods for inserting/selecting data from the database, makes test insertion which **works fine**

**`LetterServlet`** class: takes data from a form, puts it into a database and then sends it to a page that displays the entered data - insertion **doesn't work**

**`TestBR`**: makes a test insertion into the database - **works fine**

`BaseRunner` class:

```
public class BaseRunner
{
    static Connection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        BaseRunner br = new BaseRunner();

        br.insertLetter("TestUser3", "TestLetter3");  //works fine
      }

    public BaseRunner()  {
       makeConnection("url",
                        "postgres", "pass");
    }

    public boolean makeConnection(String DB_URL, String USER, String PASS)  
     {
       connection = null;

       try {
          Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

             System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

             return true;

      } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);

             return false;
            }
    }

     public void insertLetter(String userName, String letterText)  {
        try {
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

           PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
           preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO letters VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

           preparedStatement.setInt(1, 0);
           preparedStatement.setString(2, userName);
           preparedStatement.setString(3, letterText);

           preparedStatement.executeQuery();

       }
        catch (Exception e)  {
           System.out.println("Exception insert");

           e.printStackTrace();
           System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
           System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

`LetterServlet`:

```
package com.web;

import com.util.BaseRunner;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


public class LetterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String letterText = request.getParameter("letterText");

        BaseRunner br = new BaseRunner();
        br.insertLetter("TestServletUserReal", "TestServletTextReal");  //doesn't work

        RequestDispatcher view= request.getRequestDispatcher("letter_sent_view.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

`TestBR`:

```
package com.web;

import com.util.BaseRunner;

public class TestBR {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseRunner br = new BaseRunner();
        br.insertLetter("TestBR", "TestBRText");  //works fine
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the `LetterServlet`'s database insertion doesn't work even though it's no different from insertions performed by `BaseRunner`'s or `TestBR`'s `main` methods.

Comment: You really should not use things like `System.exit(0)` in your exception handling. That will exit the JVM which is not something you want in a server process that hosts servlets. In any case, your code should produce exceptions (but logging is probably not done by your incorrect use of `System.exit`), include those tracktraces in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are insert data,it will update the database record,so you should not use `query` instead you need to use `update` in your `insertLetter` method

Change

```
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

to

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I wonder though, why did `executeQuiery()` work fine for both `BaseRunner` and `TestBR`, but didn't for `LetterServlet`?